# OSHA Inspection Enforcement Data, Migrant Labor Inspection Variable

Tags: labor

Does anyone have more information about how OSHA classifies certain inspections as migrant labour inspections? The frequency of these migrant labour inspections seems low relative to the number of migrant labourers we have in the country, so I was wondering if there are additional criteria for an inspection to qualify as a migrant labor inspection. The webpage does not provide any additional information https://developer.dol.gov/health-and-safety/dol-osha-enforcement/.